# How to detect when whole subscribes in a loop end in a angular2+ application?

Tags: angular, typescript, asynchronous, subscribe

I'm using angular 13 with typescript.
I have a Service class containing a method that performs a get request against a rest api :

```
getProduct(productId): Observable<Product> {
    const productUrl = `http://localhost/api/products/${productId}`;
    return this.httpClient.get<Product>(productUrl);
}
```

and an array of products id like :

```
let productIds: string[] = ['1', '2', '3', '4', ...];
```

now I want to call the getProduct() method for all product ids and when calling for all ids finished, do another action. Actually, I want to detect when the process for all products id finishes. calling the getProduct() method in a for loop like what I did in the following code does not meet my requirement because it acts in an asynchronous manner and the code after the loop executes immediately while I want to wait for all products to finish!
Here's the code for calling getProduct():

```
async getAllProducts() {
    for(const productId of this.productIds) {
      let product : Product = await this.productService.getProduct(productId).toPromise();
      .
      .
      // do some other actions
    }
}
```

and another method in the same class :

```
foo(){
    this.getAllProducts();
    // now I want the rest of the code in here to run only when getAllProducts() finish its work
}
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: I think forkJoin (https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/combination/forkjoin) can solve your problem. forkJoin takes as argument list of requests. 

forkJoin([...this.productIds.map(productId => this.productService.getProduct(productId)]).subscribe(([...products]) => ...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it like this code below:

```js
public getAllProducts(): Observable<any> {
  const products$: Array<Observable<any>> =
    (this.productIds || []).map((productId) =>
      this.productService.getProduct(productId)
    ) || [];
  return forkJoin(products$);
}

foo(){
  this.getAllProducts().subscribe((result) => {
    // now I want the rest of the code in here to run only when getAllProducts() finish its work
    console.log(result);
  });
}
```

**Update:** Add Promise

Or if you still want to using promises, then you can use code below:

```js
public getAllProducts(): Promise<any> {
  const promises: Array<Promise<any>> = (this.productIds || []).map((productId) =>
    this.productService.getProduct(productId).toPromise()
  ) || []
  return Promise.all(promises);
}

async foo(){
  const products = await this.getAllProducts();
  console.log(products)
}
```